# How to run multi device app in rad 10 Berlin with Android as target?

Tags: android, rad, delphi-10.1-berlin, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I am trying to run a multi-device app in RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin. Below is what my target Platform looks like:

[image]

I tried signing the app by creating a keystore file (I hope that's the way to do it) in "Project > Options > Provisioning".

I want the app to run in an emulator, not in a connected Android device. Is there any specific steps I missed?

Comment: Did you read the documentation yet? [Developing Multi-Device Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Developing_Multi-Device_Applications), [Android Mobile Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development), and [Creating an Android Emulator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_an_Android_Emulator). Whether you run the app in an Android emulator or on an Android device, the IDE does not know the difference, as long as Android's ADB (Android Debug Bridge) can talk to either one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you. I had gone through the first link. The second link does not exist. I done a complete installation of RAD Berlin in vmware with 64 bit windows 10. I created Emulator using AVD manager ( hope thats the way ) Then created a Multi device delphi project, changed the style and target to android. Put a lable inside and trying to build, deploy and run the app in android platform. As you can see from the above image in target why its showing a red error sign ?

Comment: This link works: [Creating an Android Emulator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Creating_an_Android_Emulator)

Comment: In earlier version like 4,5,7 I got vmware with everything working properly. But In this berlin edition its getting more difficult to find things in proper place. Thank for the link @RemyLebeau That link is for XE7 I got that working and also setting up android platform was pretty straight.